# how to bind data to dropdown dynamically using knockout.js?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, jsonp, single-page-application

I am new to knockout.js. I wasn't able to bind data from api to dropdown using knock out js.

My Json data from api and dropdown is:

```
[{
ContactID: 0,
FirstName: "Aaa",
LastName: "bbb",
MobileNumber: null,
StartDate: "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
EndDate: "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
},
{
ContactID: 0,
FirstName: "Ccc",
LastName: "ddd",
MobileNumber: null,
StartDate: "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
EndDate: "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
}
]
<select id="selectmenu1" name="" data-theme="c" data-bind="optionsCaption: 'Choose...'">        </select>
```

I just to bind firstname,lastname,contactID to dropdown and display firstname and lastname as text and contactID is the value field for that item.
Could anyone please give some suggestions regarding this?

Comment: you just need to use http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use the [`options` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html), where you need to specify:

- your array of items in the `options` (see in doc Example 3)
- you need to set the `optionsValue: 'ContactID'` to have the ContactID as the value
- you need to specify a function in the `optionsText` which builds your select texts (see in doc Example 4)

So your final binding will look like:

```
<select id="selectmenu1" name="" data-theme="c" 
  data-bind="options: contacts, 
             optionsValue: 'ContactID', 
             optionsText: function(i) { return i.FirstName + ' ' + i.LastName }, 
             optionsCaption: 'Choose...'">        
</select>
```

Demo [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/BJuEh/)

Comment: Hi nemesv, thanks for your reply. but i am getting above data from WEBAPI.. but you hard coded the values. Please tell me to create view modal in knock out js and bind the values to dropdown

Comment: There are a ton of article exist about how to use webapi or knockout: you can start with http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=875. I've helped you with your binding because your question was only about it. If you have further concrete problems ask them in different questions.

Comment: Hi nemesv, thanks. but it doesn't show "Choose.." as default text in that dropdown???It showing only while clicking that option..

Comment: If you have the `optionsCaption: 'Choose...'` then it should work, as works in my demo. How is your current `select data-bind ` look like?

Comment: Hi nemesv, I don't actually understand the code I am trying to use can you write everything for me and the more you answer the more I will ask?

Comment: Hi nemesv, its showing blank as dropdown. If i click dropdown then it showing "choose.." as first text in that dropdown.. why?

Answer (score 0):

You can use knockout mapping plugin. More details is 
[here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/json-data.html)

And also you can look at great 
[tutorial about how to load and save data](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=loadingsaving)